# Multiple native mobile apps on the same Facebook app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Can I have multiple apps in AppStore and PlayStore use single Facebook App? For example I own a brand and launch 3 or 4 or 5 apps under the same app on the both platforms. I want to have shared friends list between them and maybe some other things.

Comment: No, that is not possible. But you can add apps to a business - that allows you to identify the user across those different apps. But I am not sure if sharing friend lists etc. is even allowed by Facebook. It is certainly not a thing the user would expect, when they only granted one single app permission. (And doing things the user would not expect are usually not allowed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can. [See here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#faq_105681056526435)

> You can use one Facebook app ID in multiple Android apps. Just use the
>   same app ID in another app for login, sharing, and so on.
>
> For deep linking and opening your app through notifications and other
>   means, we only support a single package name/class name combination.

Comment: Is there any limits? like how many android apps I can adde for one Facebook app ID ?